# Transform from wide to long with multiple columns and keep relationship in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I understand how to convert my data from wide to long and vice versa; however, where I'm struggling is in keeping the relationship between 2 columns in the conversion.

Data is in a Pandas Data Frame. I can split each column independently using .split() and .expand(). Where I'm struggling is maintaining the relationship across the columns that the first value in the string list is related to the first value in the string list of the second column, and so on.

Original Data:

| ID | History | Relationship |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 555 - Pancreatic cancer,444 - Hypertension | 1 - Mother,2 - Father |
| 567 | 77 - Stroke | 2 - Father |

This is what I want:

| ID | History | Relationship |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 555 - Pancreatic cancer | 1 - Mother |
| 123 | 444 - Hypertension | 2 - Father |
| 567 | 77 - Stroke | 2 - Father |

I've tried searching multiple terms, but can't seem to find a similar question.

Comment: Please [edit] to add your code. We need to know what format the data is in (Pandas DataFrame?) and what you've already tried. For reference, see [mre]. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: If you're using Pandas, this may be a duplicate: [Split (explode) pandas dataframe string entry to separate rows](/q/12680754/4518341)

Comment: Edited. Looks like explore will work. Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the explode post suggested above. This does seem to work. Open for more efficient options.

```
df= df.assign(var1=df.History.str.split(','))
df= df.assign(var2=df.Relationship.str.split(','))
df_new = df.explode(["var1", "var2"])
```